# US visa denied second time under section 214(b)

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I applied again for the visit visa after rejection. The reason I was told before was that I am unemployed, I haven't traveled alone internationally and I am not graduated.

Now for a background I applied for a visit visa for clinical electives but it got denied. I applied again with the employment letter, recent travel to UAE and letter from the hospital but this time he said you don't qualify for a visa. I asked is there a specific reason, he said this letter will explain the reason and handed me the white letter.

Now I am clueless of what to do. I have this one time chance to do electives and one observer-ship as well. Anyone with any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You say the agent handed you a letter which will explain why you don't qualify for a visa. What does this letter say? What exactly are the 'clinical electives' and 'observership' that you intend to do? Is it possible they would fall under the category of 'work', which is not allowed under a visitor visa?

Comment: i am recent medical graduate. these two things are like going to the hospital and rotate as a medical student and at the end you get the LoR. the letter states that i have been denied us visit visa under section 214 b

Comment: And that would qualify as work, hence the rejection.

Comment: i have paid for these electives, now what should i do to better increase my chances?

Comment: Retrieve your money. You are not coming to the USA

Comment: i can't refund the money. its gone

Comment: Any chance you can reveal the program? Maybe email me if you don't want it public (mkennedy at gmail dot com? I'm a bit suspicious of it. You even say that you have an employment letter. If that's the case, you need a different type of visa.

Answer (score 3):

> **US visa denied second time under section 214(b)**

Section 214(b) of the Immigration and Nationality Act says that applicants for non-immigrant visas must show evidence that they will not immigrate.

Some causes for refusal include

- limited ties to home country (young, unmarried, unemployed, rural, no property)
- students lacking adult-like ties to home country
- match profile of people who previously entered on a visit-visa and stayed.
- pattern of long visits suggest intent to live in USA

and many others

> **Now I am clueless of what to do.**

I think you either need to pay for expensive professional help (but be careful not to get tricked by fraudsters claiming they can help) or give up on this one-time opportunity, either look for opportunities elsewhere or hope that new opportunities arise when you have taken time to establish strong ties to your home country.

---

Typical [guidance from a US embassy](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-refusals-belfast/visa-refusals-under-section-214b-of-the-immigration-and-nationality-act/) is

> Under Section 214(b) of the Immigration and Nationality Act (INA), applicants are presumed to be intending immigrants unless they credibly demonstrate, to the consular officer’s satisfaction, that their economic, family, and social ties outside the United States are strong enough that they will depart at the end of their authorized stay and that their intended activities in the United States will be consistent with the visa status.
>
> If your application for a visa has been refused under Section 214(b) INA, there is no appeal process.  While you are not prohibited from reapplying for a visa, unless you can show credible, new, and compelling ties outside the United States, and that your intended activities in the United States are consistent with the visa class, a different outcome is unlikely.

Note the need for credible, **new** and **compelling** reasons.

Comment: my parents are in my country, my family is here. what other ties do i need to work on?

Comment: @safa: I guess at least some of : good job, regular savings into a bank account, own house, marriage, children, etc. Obviously these are not things you can establish quickly or easily.

Comment: i don't want to let go of this opportunity like that. my job will start soon. What if I apply to simply go for new year to my sisters. Is that a good enough reason?

Comment: @safa: If you apply for a visit visa to see a relative in the USA, your previous visa application refusal history is likely to count against you, I think USA officials might wonder if you are trying to deceive them. You may be asked to explain why you no longer want to take up the electives and observership. However I am not a USA official and cannot predict what they might or might not do. I know two refusals in a short time is bad, a third refusal might lead to even worse outcomes. Maybe the US hospital can advise?

Comment: hospital not really